# scrapy csvpipeline to export csv according to spiders name or id

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have two different spiders running. I was looking to write 2 different csv files named after spider name. 
**spider1.csv** data from **spider1** and s**pider2.csv** for data from **spider2**

Here's my **CsvPipeline** class:

```
class CsvPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.file = open("ss.csv", 'wb')
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file, unicode)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    del item['crawlid']
    del item['appid']
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement the following methods:
`open_spider(self, spider):`

This method is called when the spider is opened.

**Parameters**: `spider (Spider object)` – the spider which was opened

```
class CsvPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.file = open("%s.csv" % (spider.name), 'wb')
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file, unicode)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    del item['crawlid']
    del item['appid']
    return item
```

for more: [scrapy pipeline documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline)

Answer (score 4):

There's an already inbuilt feed exporter. See [scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#csv)

In short you only need to add these to your settings.py:

```
FEED_URI = 'somename.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

You can also set these settings per spider:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'myspider.csv'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [named parameters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters) in a [FEED_URI](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_URI) setting, which are replaced by spider attributes:

```
FEED_URI = '%(name)s.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent scrapy versions, the `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` settings have been deprecated in favor of the `FEEDS` setting.

So, what could be defined as (as mentioned in [@paul trmbrth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43292052/5437511)'s answer):

```py
FEED_URI = '%(name)s.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

Now should be defined as:

```py
FEEDS = {
    '%(name)s.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
    }
}
```

I think this is more elegant than overriding the feed uri for each spider or implementing a custom pipeline to do what the feed exporter already does.

(Hope this helps anyone that may find this question but is using a more recent scrapy version.)